# Question about System.out.printf / Question about output

Tags: java

The questions are below. Here's the code: 
Short explanation of the program: I made two classes. In the class Airplane i defined the attributes for each airplane. In the class Main I created the objects for the class Airplane (the objects are the airplanes). The goal is that the program prints out  the specifiactions for the asked airplane.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Airplane a320 = new Airplane();
    Airplane a747 = new Airplane();
    Airplane avro85 = new Airplane();
    Airplane a380 = new Airplane();

    a320.type = "Airbus 320";
    a320.idNumber = 1;
    a320.seats = 165;
    a320.velocity = 890;
    a320.range = 12600.00;

    a747.type = "Boeing 747";
    a747.idNumber = 2;
    a747.seats = 436;
    a747.velocity = 907;
    a747.range = 13700.00;

    avro85.type = "Avro RJ 85";
    avro85.idNumber = 3;
    avro85.seats = 93;
    avro85.velocity = 760;
    avro85.range = 2200.00;

    a380.type = "Airbus 380";
    a380.idNumber = 4;
    a380.seats = 516;
    a380.velocity = 907;
    a380.range = 12000.00;



    a380.printInfo();    //WHY DOES THIS ONLY PRINT THE TYPE???

  }

}


public class Airplane {


    String type;
    int idNumber;
    int seats;
    double velocity;
    double range;

    public void printInfo() {
      System.out.printf(this.type, this.idNumber, this.seats, this.velocity, this.range);
    }    
}
```

Questions: 1) Why do I have to write `System.out.prinf();` instead of `System.out.println(); 2) When I run the program, it compiles. That is fine. But it only prints me out the attribute "type". How can I change the program that it prints me out all the specifications?

Beforehead I thank for all answers. It would be nice if you could also explain me the causes for my code-failure.

Thank you.

- Bakeaynado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Answer1:***

First of all you have to understand the difference in println and printf.
The names are short versions of their function. **println** is short for "print line", meaning after the argument is printed then goes to the next line. 
**printf** is short for print formatter, it gives you the ability to mark where in the String variables will go and pass in those variables with it. This saves from having to do a long String concatenation. Here are a few examples, I will be putting '_' where the computer is left and where it would put stuff if sent another print statement.

println statement:

```
System.out.println("Happy New year 2020!");
```

Result printed to the User in the console:

```
Happy New year 2020!
_
```

printf statment:

```
String var_year = "2020"

System.out.printf("Happy New year %s!", var_year);
```

Result printed to the User in the console:

```
Happy New year 2020!_
```

Since you are using printf statement , that's why its only printing the "type" attribute and ignoring the rest.

***Answer2:***
You can use the println and changed the code like :

```
System.out.printf(this.type +" "+ this.idNumber +" "+  this.seats +" "+  this.velocity +" "+  this.range);
```

I would say you can make your above statement more descriptive.

Comment: I appreciate that you took this effort. You can explain very good!

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to write printf,you can use println but you have to replace "+" instead of ",".